# Ariadne Python : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphql.type'

Tags: python, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I am getting following error when using latest `ariadne 0.16.1` with `graphql-core 3.2.3` and Python 3.10. It's a FastAPI app.

`from fastapi import FastAPI`
`from ariadne.asgi import GraphQL`

Second line throws the error

`from graphql.type import GraphQLEnumType, GraphQLNamedType, GraphQLSchema ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphql.type'`

I tried changing libraries versions both upgrading and downgrading but no luck.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

issue is resolved. There was a graphql directory in the project. renaming it fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: The documentation suggests is should just be `from graphql import...`, without the `.type`.

Comment: @TimRoberts error is thrown from the ariadne package..I have not imported it explicitly in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in a `graphql/` directory then Python is confused about the modules and tries to find `graphql/types.py` in your directory instead of the package one.

If that's the case then rename your `graphql/` directory to something else, e.g. `graphql_api/`.