# No module named 'graphql.type' in Django

Tags: python, django, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I am New in `Django` and `GraphQL`, following the the [article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/channels-ariadne/),
I am using **python 3.8 in virtual env** and **3.10 in windows**, but same error occurs on both side, also tried the this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983324/ariadne-python-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-graphql-type), i also heard that GraphQL generate queries, But dont know how to generate it, But this error occurs:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ariadne/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .enums import (
  File "/home/talha/ve/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ariadne/enums.py", line 17, in <module>
    from graphql.type import GraphQLEnumType, GraphQLNamedType, GraphQLSchema
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphql.type'```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these following ways,
One, you can find graphql directory in the project, on python path. renaming it will fix the issue.
And also you can try these commands,

```
pip install pip --upgrade
pip install setuptools --upgrade
pip install gql[all]
```

Hope this helps, if not please let know. Thanks

Comment: commands not working, can you describe other solution? my project name is graphql, should i remane it???